# Inject the Servlet object in a CDI pojo on glassfish

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi

I'm quiet new in the Java EE6 world (however, JEE5, I know well enough).

My environment is Glassfish 3.1.2

I'm trying to inject servlet objects in a CDI bean (a pojo annotated with @Named and @*Scoped) which is called for a jsp with ${nameofBean.nameofMethode(par1...)}

I try this:

```
@Inject
private ServletContext context; (or HTTPServletRequest or HttpServletResponse (for calling sendRedirect))
```

Which gives me the following deployment exception: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [ServletContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point

Apparently, on JBoss, this might work: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html

One idea I had was to use the @Produces, but till now, I didn't figure out how to do it.

Perhaps a word why I want to do this:
I want to do some CRUD stuff, but I don't really know how to handle the exceptions. So my idea is: creating a CDI Bean, which is called by the JSP and which calls some ejb in the backend. If an EJB throws an exception, I want to catch this in the CDI Bean and to something with the request object (redirect somewhere, set a message...). With the injection of the servlet context, I would also have access to the POST parameters.  I want do avoid using servlets to back the jsps and to make the connection with the ejbs (I think this is too ld-fashioned).

Thanks for your help

Yves

Comment: My solution: Create a webfilter, which set the http-response and -request object in a cdi-beans with a request scope. The beans may now been injected in every other bean and I have my access to this two objects. This solution seams to work for me, currently. Any comments?

Answer (score -1):

A reference to the `ServletContext` is injected with Weld using `@Resource`:

```
@Resource
private ServletContext servletContext;
```

However, you cannot inject `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`. For that you need a servlet filter that stores the request and response object. [Seam solder](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SolderHome) provides this capability.

I'm not an expert in front-end engineering using JSF or JSP, but I'm convinced, that a more appropriate way to handle exception than using `ServletContext` or response objects exists...

Comment: This produce me a runtime exception: In my bean which in annotated with \@Name an which calls the ejb (injected by @ejb), i add \@Resource
private ServletContext context; and the exception is: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'full.qualify.name.of.class/context'

Comment: @Yves: I'm sorry, the field name has to be `servletContext`. Corrected  my answer.

Comment: @Yves: It's not the problem of the name. `@Resource` only works for EJBs. I suggest you add `@Stateless` to your managed bean.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please read my comment on the question. What to you think about this solution?